# Include twig template with values for nested placeholder?

Tags: twig

I have a link template:

link.twig:

```
<a class="something" href="{{ url }}">{{ text }}</a>
```

And im calling the template and passing it values:

page.twig:

```
{% include "link.twig" with {'url': 'www.google.com', 'text': 'Search engine} %}
```

This was working but now I need to have url and text as part of a link object:

```
<a class="something" href="{{ link.url }}">{{ link.text }}</a>
```

How can I pass values from page.twig? The following gives me a white screen of death:

```
{% include "link.twig" with {link.url: 'www.google.com', link.text: 'Search engine} %}
```

Comment: `with { link : { 'url' : 'www.google.be', 'text' : 'Google', }, }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly include an array :

```
{% include "link.twig" with {link : { url: 'www.google.com', text: 'Search engine'} } %}
```